# ESP32-C3 Deep Sleep Wake-Up

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am having trouble with getting the ESP32-C3-DevKit-M1 to wake up from deep sleep. I have reached out on other forums and have been told that the code works for them, but unfortunately, it does not seem to work for me.

```
#include "esp_sleep.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"

#define INTERRUPT_PIN 3
RTC_DATA_ATTR int bootCount = 0;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);
   delay(1000);

   ++bootCount;
   Serial.println("Boot number: " + String(bootCount));

   print_wakeup_reason();

   Serial.println("Starting");
   delay(2000);

   for(int i=3; i!=0; i--){
   Serial.println(i);
   delay(1000);
}

Serial.println("Going to sleep now");

pinMode(INTERRUPT_PIN, INPUT);
esp_deep_sleep_enable_gpio_wakeup(1 << INTERRUPT_PIN, ESP_GPIO_WAKEUP_GPIO_HIGH);
gpio_set_direction((gpio_num_t)INTERRUPT_PIN, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);  // <<<=== Add this line
esp_deep_sleep_start();

Serial.println("This will never be printed");
}

void loop() { }

   void print_wakeup_reason() {
   esp_sleep_wakeup_cause_t wakeup_reason;

   wakeup_reason = esp_sleep_get_wakeup_cause();

   switch (wakeup_reason) {
       case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_EXT0:
          Serial.println("Wakeup caused by external signal using RTC_IO");
          break;
       case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_EXT1:
          Serial.println("Wakeup caused by external signal using RTC_CNTL");
          break;
       case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_TIMER:
          Serial.println("Wakeup caused by timer");
          break;
       case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_TOUCHPAD:
          Serial.println("Wakeup caused by touchpad");
          break;
       case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_ULP:
          Serial.println("Wakeup caused by ULP program");
          break;
       default:
          Serial.printf("Wakeup was not caused by deep sleep: %d\n", wakeup_reason);
          break;
     }
}
```

I do not think the problem could lie in the code if multiple others have ran it and said it had worked for them, but I provided the code just in case. I will also provide the basic breadboard setup below:

[image: Breadboard for ESP32-C3 in Deep Sleep]

The resistor value acting as a pull down is 10kohms. The output and serial monitor print the following:

[image: Serial Monitor]

[image: Output]

Any help in trying to fix this issue with waking up the esp32-c3 is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "Other forums" - this is not a forum. It is a Q&A.

Comment: please do not post pictures of text here ... post the text instead ... some people cannot view pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ESP32-C3, `ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_EXT0` and `ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_EXT1` are not available, and wakeup by GPIO return a wakeup_reason of `0x05`(`ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_GPIO`). So you need to add it in your switch..case block.

```cpp
  switch (wakeup_reason) {
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_GPIO:    // 05 - this is used by ESP32-C3
      Serial.println("Wakeup by GPIO");
      break;
    // other cases...
  }
```

BTW, if you connect the switch between the GPIO pin and GND, you can set the `pinMode` as `INPUT_PULLUP`, this will save you the need for external resistor, but in this case you will need to use `ESP_GPIO_WAKEUP_GPIO_LOW` as wakeup trigger. This is just my personal preference of using the internal pull-up resistor instead of adding external component.

```cpp
  pinMode(INTERRUPT_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  esp_deep_sleep_enable_gpio_wakeup(1 << INTERRUPT_PIN, ESP_GPIO_WAKEUP_GPIO_LOW);
```

Reference:

[Sleep Modes (ESP32-C3)](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32c3/api-reference/system/sleep_modes.html)

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. I'll explore on that idea of using the input_pullup as well. I appreciate the help!